# Oracle Sql breaking when I use encryption

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hibernate, encryption

I'm running a basic SQL command.

It's something like:

```
insert into $table (myEncryptedKey) values( ENCRYPTED_KEY);
```

When I was using a basic string for encrypted key it runs fine.

let's say "mykey"

However when I use an encrypted one say " ASDFSA//==" it fails. org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Syntax error in SQL statement error.

I tried surrounding my strings with ' ' chars ex:

"blah '" +key + "' blah"

but that doesn't seem to work.

My table is something like

```
$table
     keyvalue varchar(255)
```

and I cannot modify it at this time.

What can I do to? I still need to insert my encrypted sql query value. Also what part of it is causing the error?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use bind variables. Don't put strings into SQL directly (especially if they can contain special characters).

Comment: Is the column declared as a `varchar2` or as a `raw`?  Is the encrypted data stored in a string or a binary data type on the client?  Generally, encryption produces binary values.  Storing encrypted data in a `varchar2` is generally a bad idea because then character set conversion can make the data unreadable unless you're doing something like Base-64 encoding the encrypted data (which has implications for the size of the column you need).

Comment: @Thilo can you explain what you mean by bind variables?

Comment: They are varchar... I however do not really have the option of changing them at this time

Comment: This is tagged "hibernate". Cannot you use that to generate the SQL?